# C Socket: Долго сбрасывается соединение

Tags: c, сокет

есть такой код:

```
int read_s, str_size;
char recive_msg[TEXTSIZE_BUFER];
struct sockaddr_in server, client;

str_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
server.sin_port = htons(100);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_family = AF_INET;

for (;;) {
    int socket_r = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), clnt_r;

    setsockopt(socket_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
    setsockopt(socket_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
    printf("22\n");

    memset(server.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(server.sin_zero)); 
    if (bind(socket_r, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0)
        goto close_socket;

    printf("aa\n");

    listen(socket_r, 10);
    if ((clnt_r = accept(socket_r, (struct sockaddr *)&client, &str_size)) <= 0)
        goto close_socket;

    read_s = recv(clnt_r, recive_msg, TEXTSIZE_BUFER, 0);
    printf("close\n>%s\n", recive_msg);

close_socket:
    setsockopt(socket_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int));
    setsockopt(clnt_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int));
    close(clnt_r);
    close(socket_r);
}
```

Проблема: Когда софт выполняет SO_REUSEADDR и close(), возвращается в начале и потом секунд 20-30 циклится на printf("22\n");, только после этого идет дальше. Вопрос такой: в чем может быть причина?

Изначально у меня задумка была поделить клиент и сервер часть в 2 отдельных потока...и когда освобождается порт выполняется тот или иной поток.

Comment: а зачем делать SO_REUSEADDR перед закрытием? Его нужно делать перед bind.

Comment: Как понять?, я думал SO_REUSEADDR полностью сбрасывает сокет и его можно по новой открывать

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, работает )00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO_REUSEADDR говорит, что этот сокет можно привязать к адресу, даже если он уже привязан. Делать его перед закрытием сокета - бессмысленно. Изменять эту опцию имеет смысл только, если сокет создан, но ещё не привязан.

Comment: Для сокращения ожидания в close linger надо добавлять (как и reuseaddr все лучше установить в начале)

Answer (score 3):

В месте закрытия сокета поменять на следующий код:

```
close_socket:
  shutdown(clnt_r, SHUT_RDWR);
  close(clnt_r);
  shutdown(socket_r, SHUT_RDWR);
  close(socket_r);
}
```

по вкусу, если таймаут закрытия велик на ваш взгляд, можно добавить:

```
close_socket:
  struct linger lng = { 0, 0 };
  if (setsockopt(clnt_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER,(void*)(&lng), sizeof(struct linger)) < 0)
  {
     perror("set: linger 1");
  }
  shutdown(clnt_r, SHUT_RDWR);
  close(clnt_r);
  if (setsockopt(socket_r, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER,(void*)(&lng), sizeof(struct linger)) < 0)
  {
     perror("set: linger 2");
  }
  shutdown(socket_r, SHUT_RDWR);
  close(socket_r);
}
```

но лучше искать причину медленного закрытия.. Она легко может быть и на стороне клиента.

И в общем, с лингером не все так просто, вы изменяете запланированное поведение системы, в области очереди отправки пакетов. Это не всегда есть правильное решение.

> Если опция SO_LINGER разрешена, то вызовы close(2) или shutdown(2) приведут к
>   задержке процесса до отправки всех сообщений в очереди сокета или до
>   истечения времени задержки. В противном случае выход из вызовов будет
>   произведен немедленно и закрытие будет произведено в фоновом режиме.
>   Если сокет закрывается как часть вызова exit(2), то задержка всегда
>   происходит в фоновом режиме.

Собственно [мануал](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=socket&category=7&russian=0)

В вашем случае, разумно пересмотреть код, делать `bind` и `listen` в цикле  непонятно зачем.. 
система явно против.. :)

В цикле надо читать из сокета, и возможно отвечать, уверен что клиент ожидает общения :)

Функция `accept` и `read` должна быть в цикле, и её удобно обернуть во что то более приемлемое, для выхода из неё в случае ошибки.
Попробуйте перейти к более приспособленным оберткам, избегая использование `goto`, например:

```
do
{
   accept()
   ....
   if (error) break;
   read()
   ... // другой код
   if (noerror) break;

} while (0);

close_socket_code()...
```